# How to get notified when user window closes from signalR

Tags: c#, javascript, signalr, signalr-hub

I am able to get notified instantly when a user joins, and rejoins a group.
I do not know if I am doing something wrong here, but I cannot get notified when an user leaves.

Here is the code for starting the hub on the client.

```
$.connection.hub.start();
```

Here is what I am using to stop the connection.

```
$.connection.hub.stop();
```

The stop doesn't seem to disconnect the user, so I cannot update the other users in a group and remove that connection from their session.

Client code to be called back

```
$.connection.hub.proxies.collaboratorhub.client.joined = function (connectionId) {
    //
    console.log('joined : ' + connectionId);
};
$.connection.hub.proxies.collaboratorhub.client.joined = function (connectionId) {
    //
    console.log('Re joined : ' + connectionId);
};
$.connection.hub.proxies.collaboratorhub.client.gone = function (connectionId) {
    //
    console.log('gone : ' + connectionId);
};
```

Here is the c# code for the server side.

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    string pid = this.Context.QueryString["pid"];
    Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, pid);

    return Clients.Group(pid).joined(Context.ConnectionId);
}

public override Task OnDisconnected()
{
    string pid = this.Context.QueryString["pid"];
    Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, pid);

    return Clients.Group(pid).gone(Context.ConnectionId);
}
public override Task OnReconnected()
{
    string pid = this.Context.QueryString["pid"];

    return Clients.Group(pid).rejoined(Context.ConnectionId);
}
```

The join and rejoin work perfectly, but not the disconnected.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in the brand new project?

Comment: I'm not receiving an error. Sometimes when I add new client functions to be called back in the c# code the callbacks do not make it back to the browser, meaning the functions that are generated in the c# code and set back to the client to be called when something happens on the server.

Comment: I mean the behavior not error and my question still stands. Can you reproduce it in a new project?

Comment: @dfowler, sorry for the late reply. I restarted my development machine and all the client functions are being called back from the server now. I've noticed if I add new client function to be called on the client in the c# code that I've got to sometimes restart my machine. Is there another way that I can refresh visual studio so that changes are reflected soon as I start the browser? Almost as if the client code that is generated by SignalR is getting cashed.

Comment: Restart your machine? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: When I was attempting to add client code to be executed as callbacks on the client, like join, the client code would not be called. I'm going to add more callback functions tomorrow, and if it happens again I'll update you.